# SSRS - Opening a File location with Javascript in Action (Go to URL) expression for a new tab drops forward slashes

Tags: javascript, url, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am attempting to create a **Click Here** link in my report and have it open an image (file) in a new tab instead of replacing the report page in the browser.

```
=Fields!ManufacturerDataPlatePhoto.Value
```

> (Returns
>   file://cld-sql-01/1234/Web_live_FileUploads/iOS%20Applications/MyAssets/images/Live/20%20May%202019/asset70-13-RES8743.jpg)

This returns the image correctly, but on the same page as the report so the user would have to click back in her browser and rerun the report.

```
="javascript:void(window.open('file:///" & Fields!ManufacturerDataPlatePhoto.Value & "','_blank'))"
```

> (Returns 
>   file://cld-sql-01%5C1234%5CSEG_Web_live_FileUploads%5CiOS%20Applications%5CMyAssets%5Cimages%5CLive%5C20%20May%202019%5Casset70-13-RES8743.jpg)

Opens a new tab, but with a broken link, because the forward slashes have been replaced with `%5C`.

Any ideas how I could put the forward slashes back in?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do URL Encoding for your url, there's a good article that discuss the details on how you can do it in SSRS, here's the [link](http://capstonebi.blogspot.com/2010/04/url-encoding-in-reporting-services.html)

Comment: So the info in your link was really helpful, but it truncated the actual .jpg file leaving the Full Path. I think I'll have to keep looking, but I this is a great start!

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately any solution with JavaScript or VB Functions became too difficult because of all the ways different browsers and their versions display (or completely block) network file paths access.

It was necessary in the end to simply add a thumbnail image in the report using the image path I pulled from the DB and a note below the image to "Right-Click then Save Image".

This also provided an elegant way to provide the image automatically in Excel, Word, etc, and providing the path in the ToolTip added additional functionality to the report the client hadn't thought of as well.

Thank you Tholitz_Reloaded for your answer, I'm sorry I cannot upvote you now, but I do not have >15 reputation yet on this account yet.

[Final solution results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhI13.jpg)